# Display Link Title Instead of URL in XSL

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xslt

I'm learning XSL-as-I-Go, but I'm stuck.

My function :

```
public function SitemapHTML()
    {
        
        $xp = new XsltProcessor();
        $xsl = new DomDocument;
        $xsl->load('stylesheet.xsl');

        $xp->importStylesheet($xsl);

        $xml_doc = new DomDocument;
        $xml_doc->load('sitemap.xml');
        $xml_doc->formatOutput = TRUE;

        if ($html = $xp->transformToXml($xml_doc)) {
            echo $html;
        } else {
            return "<p>Il y a eu un problème.</p>";
        }
    }
```

My XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stmp="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTMP Sitemap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/stmp:urlset/stmp:url/stmp:loc">
    <div>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.website.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-03-24T09:25:25+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.website.com/locale/fr</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-03-24T09:25:25+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
```

Output :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxagS.png)

My question is : In the output, is it possible to display the page's title instead of its URL ? Perhaps I should use a template ? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Whole code, I'm using Laravel :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapIndex;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface;
use DOMDocument;
use XSLTProcessor;

//TODO: Change the homepage priority to 1 in the SitemapXML()
//TODO: Show the page title instead of the URL in the SitemapHTML().


class SitemapController extends Controller
{
    //XML Sitemap Index
    public function SitemapIndex()
    {
        //We add each sitemap to the index, create a new file and redirect to that file
        SitemapIndex::create()
            ->add('/sitemap.xml')
            ->add('/sitemap-activites.xml')
            ->add('/sitemap-villes.xml')
            ->writeToFile('sitemap-index.xml');
            return redirect(url('sitemap-index.xml'));
    }

    //XML Sitemap
    public function SitemapXML()
    {
        //We crawl the entire website then we create a xml sitemap.
        SitemapGenerator::create('https://www.website.com/')

            ->shouldCrawl(function (UriInterface $url) {
                // All pages will be crawled, except for 'activity' and 'metropole'
                return
                    strpos($url->getPath(), '/activity') === false &&
                    strpos($url->getPath(), '/metropole') === false;
            })

            ->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
            return redirect(url('sitemap.xml'));
    }


    public static function getHtmlTitle($url) {
        $doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url);
        return $doc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
    }

    //Create a HTML page based on the latest sitemap.xml
    function SitemapHTML()
        {
            $xp = new XsltProcessor();
            $xp->registerPHPFunctions('getHtmlTitle');
            $xsl = new DomDocument;
            $xsl->load('stylesheet.xsl');

            $xp->importStylesheet($xsl);

            $xml_doc = new DomDocument;
            $xml_doc->load('sitemap.xml');
            $xml_doc->formatOutput = TRUE;

            if ($html = $xp->transformToXml($xml_doc)) {
                echo $html;
            } else {
                return "<p>Il y a eu un problème.</p>";
            }
        }

    //XML sitemap for the 'metropolises' DB table
    public function SitemapVilles()
    {
        //Create a sitemap object
        $sitemap = App::make('sitemap');

        //Set homepage URL
        $url = 'http://www.website.com/';

        //Add the homepage URL to the sitemap
        $sitemap->add($url, today(), '1', 'daily');

        //Get all the data from 'metropolises' table
        $metropolises = DB::table('metropolises')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

        //Execute a for each loop on the 'metropolises' table and add each entry to the sitemap
        foreach ($metropolises as $metropole) {
            $sitemap->add($url . 'metropole/' . $metropole->name, $metropole->updated_at, '0.64', 'daily');
        }

        //Return the results as an xml file
        $sitemap->store('xml', 'sitemap-villes');

        //Redirect
        return redirect(url('sitemap-villes.xml'));
    }

    //XML sitemap for the 'activities' DB table
    public function SitemapActivites()
    {
        //Create a sitemap object
        $sitemap = App::make('sitemap');

        //Get all the data from 'activities' table
        $activities = DB::table('activities')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

        //Set homepage URL
        $url = 'http://www.website.com/';

        //Add the homepage URL to the sitemap
        $sitemap->add($url, today(), '1', 'daily');

        //Execute a for each loop on the 'activities' table and add each entry to the sitemap
        foreach ($activities as $activity) {
            $sitemap->add($url . 'activity/' . $activity->id . '/' . $activity->slug, $activity->updated_at, '0.8', 'daily');
        }

        //Return the results as an xml file
        $sitemap->store('xml', 'sitemap-activites');

        //Redirect
        return redirect(url('sitemap-activites.xml'));
    }
}
```

Then there's the routes :

```
//Sitemaps
Route::get('/sitemap-index', [SitemapController::class, 'SitemapIndex'])->name('sitemap-index');
Route::get('/sitemap-html', [SitemapController::class, 'SitemapHTML'])->name('sitemap-html');
Route::get('/sitemap', [SitemapController::class, 'SitemapXML'])->name('sitemap-xml');
Route::get('/sitemap-villes', [SitemapController::class, 'SitemapVilles'])->name('sitemap-villes');
Route::get('/sitemap-activites', [SitemapController::class, 'SitemapActivites'])->name('sitemap-activites');
```

I'm doing this locally. Therefore, when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-html, I should have the expected output, but I have this error : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EhVi.png)

Comment: Where in the XML is the title, or you want to parse the link and take the `<title>` element?

Comment: I guess parse the link and take the <title>.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You can actually. PHPs ext/xslt supports callbacks. However it would terribly inefficient, because you would synchronously fetch external data. Depending on how the sitemap XML is generated I would add the title in a secondary namespace.

Comment: @thW, how would you do that ? a hint please ? =)

Comment: I would add something like `<c:title xmlns:c="urn:my-content-namespace">...</c:title>` elements to the `url` elements using DOM methods. If possible I would do it while or before the sitemap XML is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how PHP/XSLT can do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stmp="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="php stmp">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Goodtime HTMP Sitemap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/stmp:urlset/stmp:url/stmp:loc">
    <div>
        <a href="{.}">
          <xsl:value-of select="php:function('getHtmlTitle', string())"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PHP

```
function getHtmlTitle($url) {
    $doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url);
    return $doc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
}

function SitemapHTML()
    {
        
        $xp = new XsltProcessor();
        $xp->registerPHPFunctions('getHtmlTitle');
        $xsl = new DomDocument;
        $xsl->load('parse-site-map1.xsl');

        $xp->importStylesheet($xsl);

        $xml_doc = new DomDocument;
        $xml_doc->load('sitemap1.xml');
        $xml_doc->formatOutput = TRUE;

        if ($html = $xp->transformToXml($xml_doc)) {
            echo $html;
        } else {
            return "<p>Il y a eu un problème.</p>";
        }
    }
```

I would hope, however, that you have a local version of both the site map file as well as of all the linked files so that you can read them from your local file system instead of pulling them in over HTTP(S).

Comment: ErrorException
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xsltExtFunctionTest: PHP Object did not register PHP functions

Comment: @Rupersia, do you have that line `$xp->registerPHPFunctions('getHtmlTitle');`? That should take care of it.

Comment: You were right, I was editing the wrong file. But now I have this error : XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Unable to call handler getHtmlTitle().
Perhaps this is a hint : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37091 ?

Comment: You will need to show exactly what you are doing when you get the error, the sample I posted avoided complexity of classes as I couldn't tell from your snippet in the question how you use them and as I wanted to show a sample and example of the API use. But I am anyway not an expert on advanced PHP, so perhaps someone else can chime in and tell whether and if so, how it is possible to call a method instead of a global function.

Comment: I made an update.

Comment: @Rupersia, try whether `$xp->registerPHPFunctions('SitemapController::getHtmlTitle');` instead of `$xp->registerPHPFunctions('getHtmlTitle');` helps, plus `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('SitemapController::getHtmlTitle', string())"/>` . But I would also explore any options to just store the title while the site is crawled for the sitemap. Perhaps ask that as a different question.

Comment: ErrorException XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Unable to call handler SitemapController::getHtmlTitle().
I'll try to figure this out somehow. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you need the fully qualified path e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('App\Http\Controllers\SitemapController::getHtmlTitle', string())"/>`

Comment: I did that, then I had some bugs, which were solved by changing a little bit your code to : $doc = new DOMDocument(); @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url) ... But now I have : Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null.